# Redis namespace

Tags: python, redis

I want to store a key in two different 'namespaces'. For example:

```
r.set('1', 'Hello') # in the N1 set
r.set('1', 'Goodbye') # in the N2 set
```

How would I do this in redis? That is, how would I create it, and then how would I fetch it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typical naming convention for REDIS objects is `"{object_type}:{id}"` (and  `"{object_type}:{id}:{field}"`). For example you could do:

```
r.set('greeting:1', 'Hello') 
r.set('farewell:1', 'Goodbye')
```

Comment: Is doing `greeting.1` an acceptable convention as well?

Comment: @Hockey127: `:` is more common, but it's just a convention, so whatever floats your goat.